# In PHP how do I do a substring after a particular word?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a string like this:

Title December 15, 2016/0 Comments/topic/by joe blow Facebook Twitter Google+ LinkedIn My really important content that I want to display. I don't care about the title and social media words.

I'd like to strip the string to show everything after the word "LinkedIn ".

Comment: Can you please quote your complete string ?

Comment: use string split on 'linkedin'

Answer (score 3):

You can do so using the [explode function provided by php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
$str = "December 15, 2016/0 Comments/topic/by joe blow Facebook Twitter Google+ LinkedIn My really important content that I want to display";
$arr = explode("LinkedIn", $str);
echo(trim($arr[1]));
```

Output

```
My really important content that I want to display
```

Comment: Also Please add semi colons after the statements. ;)

Comment: got whitespace on the beginning of string

Comment: whitespaces can be taken care by trim() in php

Comment: One vote for obeying me.. ;)

Comment: I primarily fo swift and python, semi-colons are somewhere deep in the abyss of my brain

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) it will start the string from which word or letter you want.

```
$str = "December 15, 2016/0 Comments/topic/by joe blow Facebook Twitter Google+ LinkedIn My really important content that I want to display";

        $str= strstr($str, 'LinkedIn');
        $str = trim($str,'LinkedIn');
        echo $str;
```

Comment: will include `LinkedIn` part of the string

Comment: Now it will remove linkedin :)

Comment: 1 voteup..next remove whitespace :)

Comment: Thanks! space is not appearing before string :)

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
$str = "Title December 15, 2016/0 Comments/topic/by joe blow Facebook Twitter Google+ LinkedIn My really important content that I want to display. I don't care about the title and social media words.";
$needle = "LinkedIn";
$pos = strpos ($str, $needle);
$substr = trim(substr($str,$pos + strlen($needle)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `strpos` , `strlen`  and `substr` !!

```
$str = "December 15, 2016/0 Comments/topic/by joe blow Facebook Twitter Google+ LinkedIn My really important content that I want to display";
$index = strpos($str, "LinkedIn"); // find from witch character "LinkedIn" starts
$index += strlen("LinkedIn"); // add "linked in length to $index"
$res = substr($str, $index);  // separate that number of characters from your string
echo $res;
```

Comment: Nice but lengthy.